# Bash create while loop to remove all files within a directory

Tags: bash

Trying to create a while loop to remove 8 files from a specified test folder. I keep getting the error `no such file or directory` even though I am positive I am in the right folder because I can use the `ls` command to see the files... Anyways here is what I have

```
#!/bin/bash

var=(`ls ~/Random/Unit1/Test`)
x=${#var[@]}
i=0

while [ $i -lt $x ] ; do
    rm $var                   # this line is incorrect and needs changing
    ((i++))
done
```

Comment: Add quotes to `$var`: `rm "$var"`

Comment: Still does not work correctly... I get the error `rm: cannot remove `file1': No such file or directory`

Comment: How about `rm -f ~/Random/Unit1/Test/*.*`?

Comment: You have to change the current directory for `rm` to work, see my answer bellow for a way to do it

Comment: Why not use `find ~/Random/Unit1/Test type -f -exec rm -f {} \;` or even simpler `rm -f` as per @DarshanPatel's comment?

Comment: Why are you using the external program `ls`?  What's wrong with `var=(~/Random/Unit1/Test/*)`?

Comment: @DarshanPatel: filenames might not have a `.` in them :-)  `*`, rather than `*.*`?

Comment: @cdarke agree with you. But I prefer `*.*` in my daily life rather than `*` and here I am just trying to suggest one liners instead of whole script.

Comment: @DarshanPatel:  fair enough, its just that `*.*` seems a bit Windowsy to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your script, the first one is that you should `cd` to the folder from where you want to remove the files, you can use `pushd` and `popd` for it. Second, you should enclose the `var` variable with double quotes. Also, as stated in [@redball's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29713011/1041822), you are accessing an array, you have to use array notation on it.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRECTORY=~/Random/Unit1/Test
var=(`ls $DIRECTORY`)
x=${#var[@]}
i=0

# Saves current directory and change it to the one pointed by "$DIRECTORY"
push "$DIRECTORY" 

while [ $i -lt $x ] ; do
    rm "${var[$i]}"
    ((i++))
done

# Restores the previously saved directory
popd
```

Answer (score 1):

var is an array variable, right now you're accessing it as a scalar, which in bash returns the first value, so you remove the first file and then try to remove it again once for every file in the directory. If you want to remove every file you need to get the value of the array at every index, so in the loop you would get the nth value in the array, ie

```
rm ${var[$i]}
```

Comment: Now I get the error `rm: cannot remove file1: No such file or directory` but It goes from file1 through file8... Thats close